# How do I send email with django-registration?

Tags: python, django

How do I send email with django-registration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) sends an email to the user, e.g. when he or she registers. The process is as follows (if this was your question ...)*:

- The user has filled out and submitted the registration form ...
- in `views.py:187`

  ```
  new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
  ```
- in e.g. `backends/default/__init__.py:78`

  ```
  new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
     password, site)
  ```
- in `models.py:79`

  ```
  if send_email:
      registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)
  ```
- and then in `models.py:207`

  ```
  def send_activation_email(self, site):
      ...
      self.user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
  ```

The last method call goes into `django.contrib.auth`, especially [`django.contrib.auth.models.User.email_user`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.email_user)

P.S. Also, it's crude, but in general a search on the codebase, e.g. with `grep` or similar tools can show you things like this.

<sub>*changeset [073835a4269f](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/changeset/073835a4269f/)</sub>